# Wrong amount of lines in printTriangle?

Tags: java

I've been doing a MOOC.fi Java course and it comes along quite well, except the Christmas Tree part. It works as intended in the output, but the system won't accept it and I don't know why.
I get this error:

> when printTriangle(1) was called, wrong amount of lines was printed expected:<1> but was:<2>

Here's the code:

```
public class AdvancedAstrology {

    public static void printStars(int number) {
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            System.out.print("*");           
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printSpaces(int number) {
        while(number > 0){
            System.out.print(' ');
            number--;
        }
    }

    public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        int star = 0;
        while(size > 0){
            printSpaces(size--);
            printStars(star++);
            
        }
    }

    public static void christmasTree(int height) {
        int h = height -1;
        int stand = height - 2;
        int s = 1;
        
        while(height > 0){
            printSpaces(h);
            printStars(s);
            s+=2;
            h--;
            height--;
        }
        printSpaces(stand);
        printStars(3);
        printSpaces(stand);
        printStars(3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The tests are not checking the main, so you can modify it freely.

        printTriangle(5);
        System.out.println("---");
        christmasTree(4);
        System.out.println("---");
        christmasTree(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `printStars(++star);` in printTriangle

Comment: don't add new line in `printStars` method.  do it in printTriangle at the end of while loop with condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing post increment, that's why in star is being passed as 0 in first iteration.

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        int star = 0;
        while(size > 0){
            printSpaces(size--);
            printStars(star++); //Here. change it to ++star
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! I spent all day on this and this little thing fixed it!

Comment: I can't edit anything yet, but the actual thing that fixed it was changing this line printSpaces(size--); // to --size